# DATEVALUE() function in VB6 and SQL Collations

Tags: sql, vb6

Does the DATEVALUE() function produce different results for different collations in SQL server.  For example, if you have two SQL servers with different collations (one American and one English) and each server has a database table, which contains a field that has the same date and the date is 01 February 2011, then can you ever expect different results using DateValue in VB6 i.e. is it possible for the datevalue to interpret the date as 02 January 2011 when extracting fron the American server.

Comment: Collation definitely doesn't have anything to do with this. If you are casting from a string format to `datetime` datatype within SQL Server itself. The language setting of the login can make a difference to how it is interpreted though. Please show some code so we can see what you are doing exactly.

Comment: @Martin here is the code: <code>dteDateFromDatabase = rs("databasedate") If DateValue(dteDateFromDataBase) MsgBox("Error") Else MsgBox("No error") End If</code>  In the example above I am wandering if the outcome of the IF statement could be different depending on the server setting i.e. whether the date setting is set to American or English. For example, could the date 02 Jan 2011 be interpreted as 01 Feb 2011

Answer (score 1):

Datevalue is ran on the client, so it is not dirrectly affected by the collation, but if you need to use it, then your SQL is returning a string instead of a date, and how that string is formatted is determined by the Dateformat setting on the server.  That isn't determined by the collation, but non-us locations might change both.

If you can control the sql, then have it return a date and there's no problem, if not, you need to determine what it does return, then use date.parseexact.